# Cypher: create node and relationship if not exists, else create relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

I am trying to use neo to create a unified data dictionary across many datasets, since many of the columns are shared. I have one dictionary as a csv per dataset, with common columns in each. I am new to graph databases, but I think the pseudo code should look like this:

1. Create dataset node (single node with name and featues of dataset)
2. Upload data dictionary for dataset in step 1
3. If field node exists, create relationship between dataset node and existing field node.
4. If not exists, create field node and relationship between dataset node and field node.

Excluding step 1 which I am doing manually for each dataset node, here is what I have so far:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:.csv" AS csvLine 
MERGE (d:data {field: csvLine.Field, dtype: csvLine.Type, format: csvLine.Format})
ON CREATE SET d.field = csvLine.Field
ON MATCH SET d.field = csvLine.Field
CREATE (dataset)-[r:CONTAINS]->(d);
```

The results appear almost correct, only new fields are created, and the number of created relationships is equal to the number of fields in the uploaded dataset. However, the (dataset) node I created previously does not connect to the fields. Instead, label-less nodes are created and attach to all the fields in the new dataset. How can I properly connect the dataset node to the appropriate fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here: `CREATE (dataset)-[r:CONTAINS]->(d)`

`dataset` is a variable, and this the first time it's used in the query, so this CREATE will create a blank node, bind it to the `dataset` variable, then create the relationship to `d`.

Variables only last for the duration of a query (or less, if they are not carried in scope with the WITH clause), and are never persisted to the database. If you previously created some node in a different query with the `dataset` variable, then that variable went out of scope when the query ended. If you want to refer to that same node again, you will need to match to that node in this query.